# CSS opacity not working in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, opacity

I have a button I have disabled using jQuery in my phone gap application. The href is removed BUT the opacity of the button is not working so it looks like a broken button. Can someone let me know a better way to go about this or a better way to have this work. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.each(rolesArray, function() {
    if (this == "USER") {
        $('#disable-button').css( 'opacity', '.5');
        $('#disable-button').removeAttr('href');
    }

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
      <a href="#search" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" id="disable-button"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Search" /></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with displaying mask with animation:

```
opacity = $(maskDiv).css('opacity'); //read the opacity from CSS file
$(maskDiv).css('opacity', 0).animate({opacity: opacity}, 500); //animate fading
```

But while this works in browsers, method css() returns wrong value in PhoneGap and the screen gets completely blank (mask opacity=1).
So I simply fixed this with hardcoding the opacity value into JS:

```
$(maskDiv).css('opacity', 0).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
```

Comment: While my problem was a bit different (phonegap 3.4 app, testing on Android 4.3), this solution worked. I used to use the jquery transit library, so had to change `$('.double-tap-vote-image').transition({ opacity: 0 }, 1500, 'ease');` to `$('.double-tap-vote-image').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1500);` for it to work on my app.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.each(rolesArray, function() {
    if (this == "USER") {
        $("#yourButton").addClass('ui-disabled');
    }

});
```

Comment: Ok, I have tried this as well in iOS and Android PhoneGap and still not setting the opacity. It does work in web browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is the "img" tag that you want to set the opacity to 0.5, not the anchor.

```
jQuery.each(rolesArray, function() { 
    if (this == "USER") { 
        $('#disable-button').removeAttr('href').find('img').css('opacity', '.5'); 
    }     
});
```

Comment: Thank Neil for the response. This seems to work in the web environment to make the logo opaque but not inside PhoneGap. I appreciate the help though :)

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).